# Law of the distance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

*You have a rectangle with sides $2$ and $3$. You choose a random point and you call $X$ the perpendicular distance from the closest side.*

*Finding the law of probability of $X$ (hint: first establishing the support of $X$)*

Honestly, I've no idea how approach the problem. I only know that we have two r.v. with Uniform distribution ($Z\sim U(0,2)\Rightarrow f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{I}_{[0<z<2]}(z)$ and $Y\sim U(0,3)\Rightarrow f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{3}\mathbb{I}_{[0<y<3]}(y)$) and a rectangular domain which makes them independent. So $f(y,z)=\frac{1}{6}$.

Could you please suggest where starting?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

As the hint says, first note that $X$ is supported on $[0,1].$

Then note that for $x\in [0,1],$ $\{x \leq X\}$ is a $2-2x$ by $3-2x$ rectangle with area $(2-2x)(3-2x)$ and therefore has probability $$\mathbb{P}(X\geq x) = \frac{ (2-2x)(3-2x) }{6}$$

Can you complete it from here?